# Source Control Merge Wizard with no target branch

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, merge, source-control-explorer

This is in Visual Studio 15 Preview 5. I have attached an image of what happens below:

[image]

For some reason, the combobox where you chose target branch is non-existing. Why? Can I fix this somehow or do I have to do all operations with commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to resize the window by pulling in the bottom edge of the dialog.

Still strange that it ended up being so small.

Comment: God damnit, you are a genius! I feel so stupid I thought it was redesigned or something... After resizing, it cannot be made this small again so it was a rare case of bad luck :) Anyway, thanks man!

Comment: jesus.   i got this too and thought the same thing!